# Display DICOM file on screen

Tags: java, dicom

I am having some trouble displaying a dicom file. I have tried many things to display the picture onto the frame but all it does is make an error which is "image is empty". Any suggestions would be appreciated. (I know that the image is not empty and that it is able to access the image from the laptop).

Thank you.

Here is my code (which is coded in java):

```
class Open{
public static void main(String s) throws IOException{
    String [] array = s.split("/");
    String k = array[0];
    k+= "/";
    k += array[1];
    k+= "/";
    k += array[2];
    k+= "/";
    k+= array[3];
    k+= "/";
    k+= array[4];
    k+= "/";
    System.out.println(k);

    System.out.println(s.length());

    if(s.length() == 0){
        System.out.println("The path and filename are empty!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    File source = new File(k, array[5]);

    final Image image = ImageIO.read(source);
    //final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(k, array[5]));

    if(image == null){
        System.out.println("The image is empty or can't be read!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0,0,240, 240);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    //{
//          public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
 ////               Rectangle box = g.getClipBounds();
 ////               ((Graphics2D)g).fill(box);
 ////               
////                if(bounds.intersects(box)){
//                  g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
 ////               }
//          }
//      };

    JLabel b = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    panel.add(b);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Dicom is not an usual data format, so don't expect it to be supported "out of the box". Search for some java library that manages them.

Comment: ImageIO does not (claim to) support all possible graphic file types. I don't see DICOM in [its list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html). Are you sure it is *supposed to* work with DICOM files?

Comment: Offtopic: code in the block `if(s.length() == 0)` will never be executed: if `s` is empty string, then you'll get 'index out of range' at the line `String k = array[0];`

Comment: I think it should work with ImageIO...cause I don't know where to get dicim libraries? Does anybody know where to get any?

Comment: Thanks for catching that I forgot to change that when I was changing my code.

Comment: I can't find any libraries on this. I thing ImageIO or BufferedImage should support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [PixelMed](http://www.pixelmed.com/). The documentation is pretty much non-existent, but there are javadocs.

If you primarily intend to display the image, you should be able to use [`SourceImage`](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/javadoc/com/pixelmed/display/SourceImage.html) and [`SingleImagePanel`](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/javadoc/com/pixelmed/display/SingleImagePanel.html) from the `com.pixelmed.display` package to load and display the image. If you want to parse DICOM attributes, you could start with one of the read methods in [`com.pixelmed.dicom.AttributeList`](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/javadoc/com/pixelmed/dicom/AttributeList.html).

Comment: how do you use imageJ or pixelmed like how do you integrate it into eclipse? Cause I was using the Dicom image IO plugin from oracle but unfortunately theres no free full version of it. So I am unsure how to use pixelmed or imageJ. I also found the oracle one very easy to understand and easy to use. Is pixelmed or imageJ easy to use? if so how do you use it? This is what I have been using: http://imaging.apteryx.fr/dicom/download/index

Comment: You use them in Eclipse just like you'd use any other external JAR, add it to your project's build path on the library tab.

Comment: Well, try them out and post your specific questions in a separated topic. Both libs have documentation links right on the front page.

Comment: okay thanks I got that but is pixelmed coded in C? cause I believe imageJ is coded in java.